# My Free Shipping is being calculated after tax is added

Tags: magento

I’m trying to setup $50 free shipping but when I add products that add up to $47.00 the tax kicks it over and allows free shipping. I can’t believe this is standard so I must have something set up wrong. I have the Free Shipping set up under the carriers, FedEx and USPS.

I have “Apply Discount On Prices = Excluding Tax” set in Config/Sales/Tax which seems to be what I’m after. I've also tried the Free Shipping method in Shipping Methods.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if I understand you correctly, you want free shipping for $50 or above. If that's so, I think a safe way to do so would be import a .csv to your shipping method with your taxes:
0 to $50, your tax
$50 - above: free

Comment: You do understand me. If a customer puts a couple of items in the cart and it adds up to $47.00 Magento adds the tax which brings the total to $50.17 and THEN the free shipping module says GREAT you get free shipping. Everything I've read says that coupons and tax shouldn't effect that. Shouldn't the code go on the subtotal?

Comment: @dalef have you got the solution of this issue? I am also facing the same. the below noth answer not work for me

Answer (score 3):

3 steps:
**1. Edit Freeshipping.php**
app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php
Look for **getBaseSubtotalInclTax** and change to **getBaseSubtotal**

**2. Setup Shopping Cart Pricing Rules.**
Go to Promotion > Shopping Cart Pricing Rules > Setup "Subtotal equals or greater than 50".

**3. Enable Freeshipping Module**
System > Configuration > Shipping Methods > Setup "Minimum Order Amount" = 50.

Boom! Your freeshipping calculation will exclude taxes.

If you don't want to modify core files. Copy the Freeshipping.php to
app/code/local/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php

Comment: I thought that would work too, James. But it does not. getBaseSubtotal is not an available method in the $request object in Freeshipping.php. But getPackageValueWithDiscount() is available and does report back a pre-tax subtotal.

Answer (score 1):

I have this configuration on my rates, and it works as you want:

**Type of tax**
Type of tax: shipping

**Calculation settings:**

Tax Calculation Method Based On     "total price"

Tax Calculation Based On        "shipping addres"

Catalog Prices                      "including tax"

Shipping Prices                     "including tax"

Apply Customer Tax          "before discount"

Apply Discount On Prices            "excluding tax"

Apply Tax On                            "personalized price if available"

**Price display settings**

Display Product Prices In Catalog       "including tax"

Show shipping price                     "including tax"

**Shopping cart display settings**

"including tax"

"excluding tax"

"excluding tax"

"No"

"No"

"No"

**Orders, invoices, credit memos display settings**

"including tax"

"excluding tax"

"excluding tax"

"No"

"No"

"No"

**Fixed product taxes**

"No"

"Including FPT only"

"Including FPT only"

"Including FPT only"

"Including FPT only"

"No"

"No"

"No"

This configuration works fine for me... Hope this helps!

Comment: You have a lot of different settings so I gave it a go but that doesn't work correctly either or should I say the way I want it to. With your settings: Catalog Prices including tax is a problem. The prices for the products are always before taxes, your way reduces the price of the product until it adds the tax which brings it up to the MSRP, I might as well not charge tax if I'm going to have to pay it.