# Calculate shipping cost based on Grand Total of basket?

Tags: magento

I’ve implemented a Table Rate Shipping system on my shop, based on a “Price vs Destination” condition. However, I’ve noticed that the shipping is calculated on the sub total of the basket (exc. VAT/Tax) instead of the Grand total (inc. VAT/Tax). How do I get Magento to base the shipping on the grand total, rather than the subtotal?

**UPDATE:** The version of Magento I'm using is Version 1.5.0.1.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I've solved this by modifying the tablerates.csv . e.g. if you have free shipping above 55€ you write in your tablerates 45 (in my country we have 22% tax so 45*1,22 = 55)

Answer (score 3):

Just on the back of the comments to huzefam's answer - you have mentioned VAT and are in the UK so I'm thinking maybe the GB language pack has been installed, in which case your path will be System -> Configuration -> Sales -> VAT submenu header -> Tax Classes and then you change the VAT Class for Delivery option.

See image below;

[image]

Comment: This path is correct, but changing the VAT hasn't made a difference. Shipping is still calculated on the subtotal (exc. VAT) when it should be calculating the shipping on the grand total of the basket.

Comment: I'm don't agree with the premise here.  Shipping cost using Price vs Destination shouldn't be calculated on the tax inclusive price simply because the shipping cost is totally unrelated to whether the customer is liable for VAT or not.  That's why there is no setting for this, it doesn't make sense to do it.

Comment: Just to elaborate: Example - 2 customers, both in Aberdeen.  One is in a customer group (ie a VAT registered business with VAT code) that isn't liable for VAT, the other is a consumer in the retail group.  They both order the same item but customer A is paying a lower shipping price than customer B (even before the taxes are applied) because it's been based on the inc VAT price and one customer group is liable for VAT whilst the other isn't.

Comment: That doesn't apply to this, as it's purely a customer group the products are going to. If the customer is exempt from VAT then this is something they claim back from the taxman in their returns, it's not up to the website to dictate it. The customer pays the VAT which is then recovered from the Taxman.

Answer (score 2):

Go to : System -> Configuration -> Sales -> VAT 
Check **Calculation settings** and  try the following settings :

> - Tax Calculation Method Based On "total price"
> - Tax Calculation Based On "shipping addres"
> - Catalog Prices "including tax"
> - Shipping Prices "including tax"
> - Apply Customer Tax "before discount"
> - Apply Discount On Prices "excluding tax"
> - Apply Tax On "personalized price if available"

source : [My Free Shipping is being calculated after tax is added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713982/my-free-shipping-is-being-calculated-after-tax-is-added)

for more informations see :

> - http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/configuration-sales-tax-calculation-settings
> - http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/configuring-general-tax-settings

Comment: I've tried this, but the shipping it still being calculated on the cart price before VAT is added to it, rather than being added afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable tax for your shipping from admin in
System>Configuration>Tax>Tax Classes>Tax Class for shipping

Hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: I've looked and the path that you specified doesn't exist?

Comment: What Magento version are you using? Path provided by @huzefam is correct.